# Proving injectivity of a general polynomial function

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I'm currently trying to prove that a certain linear mapping is injective, but am stumped as to how I would go about doing so.

I'm attempting to prove that a linear transformation $$T: P(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow P(\mathbb{R})$$ given by

$$(Tf)(x) = x(x - 1)f''(x) + (x - 1)f'(x) + f(x)$$

is injective.

The way I approached this problem is that I let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ map to the same equation and then to try and show that this implies that $f(x) = g(x)$, but I was having a hard time figuring out how I should progress to make the implication occur.

I was wondering if someone could shed some light as to if I'm somewhat on the right path and where I should go from here. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps write out $f(x)$ as $a_nx^n+\cdots + a_1x+a_0$ then do the same for $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ (in terms of the same $a_is$) and then maybe you can show that each $a_i=0$. It seems like there should be a nicer way to do it but perhaps this may work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the injectivity of $T$ can be showed as follows. Since $T$ is a linear map, it suffices  to show that $\ker T=0$. This condition yields a differential equation, but we shall not afraid  it. :-) Suppose that $f=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$ and $a_n\not=0$. Since the coefficient at the highest degree of $x$ in the polynomial $T(f)$ should be a zero, we have that $0=n(n-1)a_n+na_n+a_n=(n^2+1)a_n$. Therefore $a_n=0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try from the contrapositive approach. 
Given $(Tf)(x)=(Tg)(x)$ $\forall x$ 
Assume $\exists  x$ such that $f(x)\neq g(x)$ ...

If you can invalidate the assumption, then you have demonstrated $f(x)=g(x)$.